# How do I work around this "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format" error?

Tags: r, date, error-handling, format

I'm trying to put some finishing touches on an RMarkdown file to upload it. It was working fine until I used CSV files instead of .xlsx files. I'm trying to make a date column and then split it into separate columns for month, day, and year, and then change the column for weekdays from giving a number representing a weekday to giving the actual name instead. I have the same issue in the following block when I try to use difftime.

I keep getting these errors:

Error in charToDate(x): character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
Traceback:

1. format(as.numeric(as.Date(all_trips$started_at), "%Y-%m-%d"))
2. as.Date(all_trips$started_at)
3. as.Date.character(all_trips$started_at)
4. charToDate(x)
5. stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")

What should I do? It doesn't like as.Date() or as.numeric(as.Date()).

```
all_trips$date <- format(as.numeric(as.Date(all_trips$started_at), "%Y-%m-%d"))   
all_trips$ended_at <- format(as.numeric(as.Date(all_trips$ended_at), "%Y-%m-%d"))  
all_trips$month <- format(as.numeric(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%m"))                   
all_trips$day <- format(as.numeric(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%d"))               
all_trips$year <- format(as.numeric(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%Y"))              
all_trips$day_of_week <- format(as.numeric(as.Date(all_trips$date), "%A"))
```

Update:
My only issue remaining is with the ride length column. I want this to be displayed in minutes as mm:ss.

I used the suggestions from below to get around the started at, ended at, month, day, year, and day of week issues

```
all_trips$started_at <- as.Date(all_trips$started_at, "%m/%d/%Y")          # Gives month/date/four-digit year
all_trips$ended_at <- as.Date(all_trips$ended_at, "%m/%d/%Y")              # Gives month/date/four-digit year
all_trips$month <- format(as.Date(all_trips$started_at), "%m")             # Gives us month      
all_trips$day <- format(as.Date(all_trips$started_at), "%d")               # Gives us day
all_trips$year <- format(as.Date(all_trips$started_at), "%Y")              # Gives us a four-digit year
all_trips$day_of_week <- format(as.Date(all_trips$started_at), "%A")       # Gives us day of week as year
```

Now, I run diff time as

```
all_trips$ride_length <- difftime(all_trips$ended_at,all_trips$started_at, units = "mins")
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ride_length, value = structure(numeric(0), class = "difftime", units = "mins")): replacement has 0 rows, data has 5356572
Traceback:

1. `$<-`(`*tmp*`, ride_length, value = structure(numeric(0), class = "difftime", units = "mins"))
2. `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ride_length, value = structure(numeric(0), class = "difftime", units = "mins"))
3. stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
 .     "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA)
```

Here is some of the output for the head

```
structure(list(ride_id = c("2D3C93E50745DD18", "35897CC59E57BAF4", 
"E5E9F1F5158AD65D", "E4E9354762A63483", "3E8E99C459819F76", "EC5375236F014FA4"
), rideable_type = c("docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", 
"docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike"), started_at = structure(c(18992, 
18992, 18992, 18992, 18992, 18992), class = "Date"), ended_at = structure(c(18995, 
18995, 18994, 18994, 18993, 18993), class = "Date"), start_station_name = c("LaSalle Dr & Huron St", 
"Sacramento Blvd & Franklin Blvd", "Fairbanks Ct & Grand Ave", 
"Fairbanks Ct & Grand Ave", "Warren Park West", "Shedd Aquarium"
), start_station_id = c("KP1705001026", "KA1504000113", "TA1305000003", 
"TA1305000003", "RP-001", "15544"), end_station_name = c("Kingsbury St & Kinzie St", 
"Base - 2132 W Hubbard Warehouse", "", "", "Broadway & Argyle St", 
""), end_station_id = c("KA1503000043", "Hubbard Bike-checking (LBS-WH-TEST)", 
"", "", "13108", ""), start_lat = c(41.894877, 41.890469, 41.891847, 
41.891847, 42.001785, 41.867226), start_lng = c(-87.632326, -87.702608, 
-87.62058, -87.62058, -87.688829, -87.615355), end_lat = c(41.889177, 
41.889955, NA, NA, 41.973815, NA), end_lng = c(-87.638506, -87.680651, 
NA, NA, -87.65966, NA), member_casual = c("casual", "casual", 
"casual", "casual", "casual", "casual"), ride_length = c("18:34:12", 
"2:59:55", "1:00:01", "1:00:00", "2:32:51", "1:00:00"), day_of_week = c("Friday", 
"Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday"), month = c("12", 
"12", "12", "12", "12", "12"), day = c("31", "31", "31", "31", 
"31", "31"), year = c("2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", 
"2021")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of the date character string please ... I suspect that you want the format inside the as.Date function but need an example

Comment: I would also recommend having a look at the {lubridate} package when working with dates in R, the `ymd()` functions, and the `wday()` functions both seem like they would be useful here.

Comment: @user20650 I agree, but ... the use of `"%Y-%m-%d"` should be the _default_ format, so even moving it to within `as.Date` is unlikely to change anything?

Comment: @r2evans ; yup we need an example

Comment: `format(as.numeric(as.Date(all_trips$started_at), "%Y-%m-%d"))` doesn't make sense. as.numeric will turn a date into an integer (e.g. Jan 1, 2023 is 19358), but you can't format an integer as a date.

Comment: Here is a bit more about my issue: the values in the started_at column are dates and times. For example, the first entry is 12/31/2021 22:58

Comment: `as.Date(all_trips$started_at, format="%m/%d/%Y")` first, then anything else later

Comment: I suggest you read [`?as.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html) to see that it will try two formats automatically: `"%Y-%m-%d"` and `"%Y/%m/%d"`, after those two, it fails and you need to provide an unambiguous `format=` argument. That same doc page references `strptime`, which if you need more help on what the `%`-codes mean, you should read [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html). I suspect you'll need a bit more help, since (as others have commented) your use of `as.numeric` and such do not make sense.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @r2evans. Your format worked for the first block of code. I'm getting the same error for difftime now. Any thoughts about that one? I tried adding the "format = HH:MM" argument, but I received the same error message in addition to an unused argument warning about the format argument.

Comment: @theorema.aureum ; can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75807358/edit) your question with a selection of date/datetimes that represent your data. This will be easier for you to get help on the relevant format. Perhaps adding the results of `dput(all_trips$started_at[1:10])` to your question will be enough but if not you can tweak the examples.

Comment: You need to store the `Date`-class object and then operate on *that* from there on, not on strings. Do `all_trips$started_at <- as.Date(all_trips$started_at. "%m/%d/%Y")` (same for `ended-at`), and only then can you do all the other operations (including `difftime`). Again, this would be far easier to answer if you [edit]ed your question, put in sample data (best is `dput(head(all_trips))`) so that we can easily and directly help you. All this is taking much longer than it needs to.

Comment: @theorema.aureum ; using your data from the dput of `all_trips$started_at[1:10]` (which I called `dt`),  this `as.POSIXct(dt, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

1. First, convert your strings to `POSIXt`-class.

   ```r
   all_trips$started_at <- as.Date(all_trips$started_at, "%m/%d/%Y")
   all_trips$ended_at <- as.Date(all_trips$ended_at, "%m/%d/%Y")
   ```
2. Second, *now* you can do date-like math operations on it, such as

   ```r
   difftime(all_trips$ended_at, all_trips$started_at, units = "mins")
   ```

`difftime` *can* work on strings that are not class `Date` or `POSIXt`, but only if they are *unambiguous* (in what R thinks, not what humans think). In this casee, `as.Date` looks at `%Y-%m-%d` and `%Y/%m/%d` for formats, nothing else, so the auto-conversion within `as.Date` and therefore within `difftime` or is just flat-out wrong.

Demonstration:

```r
difftime("2020-02-02", "2020-01-01")
# Time difference of 32 days
difftime("2020/02/02", "2020/01/01")
# Time difference of 32 days
difftime("02/02/2020", "01/01/2020")
# Time difference of 396 days
```

The last one is incorrect because of what it is thinking the dates format into:

```r
as.Date("02/02/2020 00:00")
# [1] "0002-02-20"
as.Date("02/02/2020 00:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y")
# [1] "2020-02-02"
difftime(as.Date("02/02/2020 00:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y"), as.Date("01/01/2020 00:00", format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
# Time difference of 32 days
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I noticed that for the columns involving things like months and days and so forth I was using a variable that didn't exist. The only issue I'm having at the moment is the ride length using diff time. I've updated my question documentation accordingly.

Comment: Not sure. I ran `difftime(all_trips$ended_at,all_trips$started_at, units = "mins")` and it returned `structure(c(4320, 4320, 2880, 2880, 1440, 1440), class = "difftime", units = "mins")`, no error.

Comment: Thanks, I was using a variable that I renamed and didn't realize it. It's always the little things!